# Excel Style Combo Box in Google Sheets

Tags: excel, combobox, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I have an issue regarding Google Sheets.

I have a spreadsheet in Google docs that i have copied from an excel spreadsheet that I created. What I need to figure out how to do is make a combo box that that when I select an option in the list it changes the value of another cell from a 1 to 2 or 3 or 4 etc.

I have this working in excel but cant seem to figure out how to do it in sheets.

My question is, does any one know of a way to do this? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 6):

Maybe I am misunderstanding your question, but it seems to me that what you want can be achieved without any scripting (though it IS possible to script the whole thing, too):

1. For the "combo box" cell, add Data Validation selecting "List
   from a range" or "List of items" under 'Criteria' as appropriate,
   and "Reject input" option in 'On invalid data' section. This will
   make the cell show a drop-down selection of items when you click on
   the little arrow now displayed in the cell.
2. In the other cell (the one that needs to change value), enter a
   formula that  changes the cell value based on selected "combo box"
   cell value. Depending on how big your list of items in the "combo
   box" cell is, you can use either a simple [`IF()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364) formula, or go for
   a [`VLOOKUP()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318) (if data validation items are coming from a range in a
   spreadsheet), or a combination of them.

For example, based on the sheet as in the screenshot below, cells C1:C6 have Data Validation rule set to range F1:F6, and cells D1:D6 have the formula `=IF(NOT(C1=""), VLOOKUP(C1, $F$1:$G$6, 2, FALSE), "DEFAULT VALUE")` (obviously references to C1 changed to corresponding row of column D). When a value is selected from a drop-down in cells C1:C6, corresponding cell in column D changes its value to the one in column G matching selected value from column F. If no value is selected in cells C1:C6, corresponding cell in column D show "Default value" (which can be whatever you need).
[image]